# Passing an array of objects between two activities

Tags: java, android

I have an array Workout with each element being an instance of class Exercise.
The MainActivity has a 'start' button which passes control to a StartExercise activity, which displays the first instance of Exercise in the Workout array.

When the exercise has been completed, the StartExercise activity calls a Rest activity which has a one minute countdown timer.

At the end of that minute, the Rest activity 'finishes' returning control to the StartExercise activity where the next exercise in the Workout array is displayed.

I would like some advice about the best way to pass the Workout and Exercise objects between these activities. If I initialise the Workout array in the StartActivity I would have to make sure that was only done once. Which seems clumsy.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Your custom class has to implement Parcelable interface. A typical implementation of Parcelable is:

```
 public class MyParcelable implements Parcelable {
    private int mData;

    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
        out.writeInt(mData);
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<MyParcelable> CREATOR
            = new Parcelable.Creator<MyParcelable>() {
        public MyParcelable createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new MyParcelable(in);
        }

        public MyParcelable[] newArray(int size) {
            return new MyParcelable[size];
        }
    };

    private MyParcelable(Parcel in) {
        mData = in.readInt();
    }
}
```

And then you can send your data using something like that:

```
Intent intent;
intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("Workout", workout);
startActivity(intent);
```

And receive:

```
workout = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("Workout");
```

Note: Make sure each nested class of your main custom class has implemented Serializable interface

Comment: As per my understanding, you are using Rest activity just as a timer and not using any excercise or workout data there. You can simply start the Rest activity for result by startActivityForResult() method and override onActivityResult() method in your StartExcercise activity. You can set desired result (RESULT_OK or RESULT_CANCEL) in Rest method depending upon elapsed timer and start the next Excercise in your StartExcercise activity in onActivityResult() method depending upon received result.

Answer (score 0):

Using a parcelable interface implementation + the intent method provided by Oleg are good ways to do that.

And another way is to use the Singleton design pattern and store the shared data in that Singleton object.